# Handle changes in schema while streaming from Dataflow to BigQury

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a requirement where I should be able to modify the BigQuery schema at runtime while streaming from PubSub to BigQuery. I went through a couple of links like :

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/how-to-handle-mutating-json-schemas-in-a-streaming-pipeline-with-square-enix

https://medium.com/@bravnic/dataflow-dealing-with-bigquery-schema-change-64936b44ef3

However, I couldn't really figure out how to mutate the schema smoothly at runtime. Please help with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using ParDo transforms to write to BigQuery, here's what I did (using the Python SDK, but the same should apply to Java / Go as well):

- in the `setup` method of the ParDo transform:

  - instantiate the BQ client to be used for the remainder of the ParDo instance
  - get the current schema of the client
  - generate a PyArrow schema of my data and compare each field
  - add any necessary fields to the BQ schema
- in the `process` method of the transform I'm doing the actual inserts to BQ

I'm not sure how the schema could be updated using the default BQ output that Beam provides. I was constrained to use ParDo transforms for output since I needed to be able to output to different BQ tables and side outputs didn't match my use-case. Performance is quite good using the Dataflow runner.

Depending on your use-case, the PyArrow schema step might not be needed.

Comment: If I get the current schema of the client in DoFn.SETUP will I have the risk of exhausting the BigQuery API call limit?

Comment: I've implemented it the way you suggested. It's working as expected. Thanks you so much. :) But I have a couple questions: (1) I've compared the existing and new schema in processElement method, did u want this step in setup? If yes, then how? Because I cannot access the messages in setup. (2) If there are millions of messages coming in I hope I don't exhaust the API rate limits that BQ has. (100/second/user). Or will I?

Comment: Great to know it worked. My main worry when doing the schema sync in processElement is rather performance than exhausting API rate limits (setup is only rarely called). If your use-case mandates a schema sync before each batch than this should work. Just make sure that your batches are as large as possible so that you don't waste time syncing the schema for just a few elements.